# How to conditionally set selected property in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ng-options, angularjs-ng-options

I have a select-field like this:

```
<select ng-init="exchangeOption = widget.content.exchange[0]" 
    ng-Model="exchangeOption" 
    ng-options="exchangeOption.title for exchangeOption in widget.content.exchange"
    ng-change="internalLink(exchangeOption.url)">
</select>
```

As you see, right now I always select the first option. But actually the "exchanges" have a "selected"-field, which is a boolean, set to true if that option should be the selected one.

How would you do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write a method to return selected exchange option by filtering the exchanges.

```
<select ng-init="exchangeOption = getSelectedExchange()" 
 ng-Model="exchangeOption" ng-options="exchangeOption.title for exchangeOption in widget.content.exchange"
 ng-change= "internalLink(exchangeOption.url)"> </select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Struggled arround with this issue for a project but finally found that you can set the selected item by setting in your controller:
EDIT : my bad made a mistake reading my code..

```
$scope.exchangeOption = selecteditemvalue
```

Comment: Thanks, I think that would work fine also, but I used Srinivas way above now.